# Real Time Color Detection and Functioning with it

Tags: python, opencv, colors, real-time, detection

I have worked some time with OpenCV to pop the colors on the screen. At the end, I succeeded to mask the colors in different windows as in the photo below:

https://prnt.sc/qo3cjy

Was wondering what is the most efficient and a working way to make the python detect the colors, and make it to run the functions() that were written by me. For example, if green was detected, run the function hellogreen(), which will print hello green when green is detected and so on.

Source Code if needed just in case:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

      # Red color
    low_red = np.array([161, 155, 84])
    high_red = np.array([179, 255, 255])
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_red, high_red)
    red = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=red_mask)

      # Blue color
    low_blue = np.array([94, 80, 2])
    high_blue = np.array([126, 255, 255])
    blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_blue, high_blue)
    blue = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=blue_mask)

    # Green color
    low_green = np.array([25, 52, 72])
    high_green = np.array([83, 255, 255])
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_green, high_green)
    green = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=green_mask)

    # Every color except white
    low = np.array([0, 42, 0])
    high = np.array([179, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low, high)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Red", red)
    cv2.imshow("Blue", blue)
    cv2.imshow("Green", green)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: You already found the colors, what's the problem?

Comment: I want to match them, so they run different functions

Comment: For example, if red was detected, run function red()  [I will write these functions]

Comment: @MH304 for instance, if 30% was detected as red in the window, run the function that there was a red card with a high percentage detected. So I will probably use the area of the window tab. I need help in the source codes of finding the total area of the tab, and if 0.3 * thatArea == 'red', run red()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines at the end of your code (helloblue, hellogreen and hellored are your hypothesized functions):

```
b = cv2.countNonZero(blue_mask) 
r = cv2.countNonZero(red_mask) 
g = cv2.countNonZero(green_mask) 

if b >= r and b >= g:
    helloblue()
elif r >= b and r >= g:
    hellred()
elif g >= b and g >= r:
    hellgreen()

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == 27:
    break
```